# Headless gem works in IRB but not in context of cucumber test

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, headless, headless-browser

I'm having an issue with the Headless ruby gem which I am trying to use to do some web UI testing.

A simple test of the gem in IRB with the following lines works as expected:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'
headless = Headless.new
headless.start 
$browser = Watir::Browser.new
$browser.goto "www.google.com"
```

However, when I add the same lines to Cucumber test, I get the error: unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

I have tried adding the lines regrading headless to my env file like this:

```
if ENV['HEADLESS'] == 'true'
  require 'headless'

  headless = Headless.new
  headless.start

  at_exit do
    headless.destroy
  end
end
```

And then calling cucumber like this `HEADLESS=true cucumber`. And I have also tried simply adding the headless specific lines right before I create the Watir browser. Both result in the same error. Needless to say, I am stumped.

EDIT: The problem was that I had multiple versions of selenium-webdriver installed, and for some reason cucumber was defaulting to the oldest version. A simple `gem cleanup selenium-webdriver` fixed the issue. Firefox version 45.2.0 and selenium-webdriver version 2.53.4 worked for me.

Comment: What versions of `watir-webdriver` and firefox are you running?

Comment: @orde Firefox version 45.2.0 and watir-webdriver version 0.8.0

Comment: `watir-webdriver` 0.8.0 was released in June 2015, and FF 45 was released in March 2016.  So, I'd try updating `watir-webdriver` (which will update the underlying `selenium-webdriver`) and see if that fixes it.  YMMV.

Comment: @orde no luck there unfortunately. I tried it with watir-webdriver version 0.9.3. And selenium-webdriver 2.53.4. Any other ideas?

Comment: I dealt with a similar issue trying to run headless in a sinatra app. Worth a shot to put a breakpoint in one of your cucumber test cases and trying the initialization there.

Comment: Hi, Headless author here. Maybe you're running tests in parallel with the IRB prompt, and Selenium can't start because the port is occupied?

Comment: @LeonidSehevtsov Thanks for reaching out. I was not running in parallel. Is there anyway that I can verify the port is open before running cucumber?